# How can i let the MySQL innoDB support the new unicode character set, such as '\U0001f3b8'

Tags: mysql, innodb

How can I let the MySQL InnoDB support the new Unicode character set, such as `\U0001f3b8`.

The char `\U0001f3b8` is a `GUITAR` which is generated by iPhone's input method.

The problem is that it cannot be saved in MySQL DB.

The column type that saved is `VARCHAR`, I have been tried to change to `TEXT`, still not working.

The Exception is :

> Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xB8' for column
>   'message' at row 1

BTW : My working environment is python + Django

Comment: Hah... I found another way to solve this problem. use simplejson.dumps(), it will translate the \U0001f3b8 to utf8 code (like: \xxxx \xxxx) . then i can save it after translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *new unicode character set* means full UTF-8 support. You need to change your table/column collations to one that include `utf8mb4` encoding. Good old `utf8` in an incomplete implementation that only supports up to three bytes. You need MySQL/5.5 for that.

Comment: No need to assume: [`U+1f3b8`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3b8/) is an emoji character (in the [Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols_and_pictographs/) block of the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane)) and therefore, as indicated in the question, is represented in UTF-8 by the four-byte sequence `0xf09f8eb8`.

Comment: @eggyal - I'm guessing because the question does not even mention UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. our MySQL is 5.1, now i knew 5.5 can sovled this problem but i cannot upgrade it due to the history reason.

Comment: Do you have any other idea to solved this problem ??? somthing like install utf8mb4 into mysql 5.1.

Comment: No idea about MySQL 5.1. You could try `ucs2` but I don't know if it offers the full Unicode catalogue, and you'd also need to convert text when reading/writing.